# Limiting bandwidth with hashlimit (e.g. kb/s -- not connections!) doesn't work, though the man page says it should

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, rate-limiting

According to the [iptables-extensions man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAW) hashlimit can do bandwidth limiting:

> "flows exceeding 512kbyte/s" =>
>
> > `--hashlimit-mode srcip,dstip,srcport,dstport --hashlimit-above 512kb/s`

However, when I try to specify a rule like that, 1) it doesn't limit my bandwidth as I expect, 2) when I dump the rules with iptables-save, I get the same entries no matter what I put after the number (kb/s, b/s, /sec, something silly, or nothing at all):

```
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.43/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8kb/s --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.44/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8b/s --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.45/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.46/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8000 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.47/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8000b --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.48/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8000xb --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.49/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8000kb --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
```

And the relevant parts of the dump:

```
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.43/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.44/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.45/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 8/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.46/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 10000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.47/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 10000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.48/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 10000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
-A it2net -s 10.5.2.49/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 10000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j ACCEPT
```

(let's not worry about why 8000 is rounded up to 10000 ... or, should we?)

Any ideas what I'm missing? I would need to limit the bandwidth use of about 100 constantly changing users individually, so each would have only a very low limit to allow basic services (especially stupid mobile apps that can't use proxy authentication), but require signing in for everything else.

Comment: Solution: I'm 3 minor versions behind. Byte-based hashlimit is introduced in iptables 1.4.15 (Ubuntu 13.04 has  1.4.12)

Comment: Please post your solution as an actual answer when it lets you.  Then accept your answer as the right one.  This could assist others in the future with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the OP, as the answer is in a comment

> Solution: I'm 3 minor versions behind. Byte-based hashlimit is
>   introduced in iptables 1.4.15 (Ubuntu 13.04 has 1.4.12) – dakhota

Answer (score 1):

Your rules `ACCEPT` packets up to a certain rate, but is there anything after that that `DROP` the traffic when it doesn't match the rules? Either default chain policy (`-P`) or an explicit rule...

What you could do is change your rules to `DROP` traffic with `--hashlimit-above`; ex:

```
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.43/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8kb/s --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.44/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8b/s --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.45/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.46/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8000 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.47/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8000b --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.48/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8000xb --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
# iptables -t filter -A it2net -s 10.5.2.49/32 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 8000kb --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name test --hashlimit-htable-expire 3600000 -j DROP
```

The other options: default chain policy (it will block **all** traffic that doesn't match these rules), or explicit rules matching the same traffic you accept and dropping it when it doesn't match the `ACCEPT` hashlimit rules.

As for the way hashlimit mangles your rules, it looks rather odd. Will it do the same if you use distinct table names? I think it's either that you have an older version that doesn't support it, or it somehow take the /s as /sec and assumes everything else for the table is per second.